# CSS transform doesn't change CSS layout

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a flex layout that shows a long blue line then text after it.

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="width: 200px; height: 30px; background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div>There's no space between me and the blue line</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to rotate the blue line by 90 degrees:

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="transform: rotate(-90deg); width: 200px; height: 30px; background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div>There's now space between me and the blue line.</div>
</div>
```

However, now the text is not flushed with the end of the blue `div`. It seems it keeps its old width.

How can I make the rotated blue div is flush next to the text? (I've played around with `transform-view` to no avail.)

(I understand, in this example, I could just change the dimensions of the blue div, but in my actual case I'm using an SVG image, which is obviously a lot harder to change)

Comment: `transform` is *entirely* visual, it does not actually change sizes of elements. I suggest you rethink your methodology.

Comment: @Paulie_D I fear you're correct. However, this would mean I need to generate a whole new SVG image (without rotating it) in my case.

Comment: Indeed, it will depend on your actual SVG and the use case.

Comment: share your real use case and we may find a solution without transform

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif but I've now duplicated the SVG file so it doesn't need a rotate. I rotated the whole image in Inkscape, then copied and pasted each element to a new file, so it included no rotations, and then that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paulie_D pointed out, CSS transforms won't change the layout.

Instead, I altered the element so I didn't need to rotate it.

In my case, this involved rotating an SVG in inkscape, then copying each element to a new file, so no global transformations were used.